# Привязка свойства объекта в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

```
public class Dict
{
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{        
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Error
{        
    public Dict Dict { get; set; }        
    public Record Record { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public ErrorType Type { get; set; }        
    public bool Corrected { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Dict")]
    public string DictCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Record")]
    public string RecordCode { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо в ListView в WPF:
1. привязать свойство Dict объекта Error к колонке
2. поменять отображение свойства Corrected на "Да/Нет" вместо "True/False"
3. Как задать формат выводимого времени
Как сделать?

Пытаюсь привязать. в Коде пишу так:

```
InitializeComponent();            
        Database.SetInitializer(new        DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());           
        Context context = new Context();
        this.DataContext = context;            
        listView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Error>  (context.Errors.ToList());
```

в разметке

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Height="144" Width="501">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding   Path=DictCode}">Код справочника</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dict.Name}">Имя справочника</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RecordCode}">Код Записи</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date}" >Дата</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}">Тип</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Corrected}">Исправлена</GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

строка

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dict.Name}">Имя   справочника</GridViewColumn>
```

не выводит данные. что делать?

Comment: "Да/Нет" вместо "True/False", тут нужен конвертер 3. Как задать формат выводимого времени Как сделать? через StringFormat, к примеру <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, StringFormat=\{0\,15\}, ElementName=userControl}"/> вот тут https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/binding_and_styles_WPF/level20/20_1.php Связывать можно через {Binding Dict.Code}

Comment: "строка не выводит данные". странно должно, у меня сработало

Comment: Возможно у вас пустой объект Dict и вы его не заполняете?

Comment: А почему вы привязываетесь к модельному объекту? У вас запросы к базе бегут в UI-потоке?

Comment: Посмотрите паттерн MVVM, вам нужен класс-связка между представлением и моделью. Там можете формировать данные для отображения из объектов модели как угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Height="144" Width="501" ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding   Path=DictCode}">Код справочника</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dict.Name}">Имя справочника</GridViewColumn>
                  <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dict.Code}">Имя справочника</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=RecordCode}">Код Записи</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" >Дата</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Corrected, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">Исправлена</GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

код

```
public MainViewModel()
      {
         Errors.Add(new Error() {Corrected = true, Date = DateTime.Now, DictCode = "code", RecordCode = "str", Dict = new Dict() {Code = "1231223", Name = "name"} });
      }
      public ObservableCollection<Error> Errors
      { get { return _errors; } }
```

конвертер

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         var val = (bool) value;
         if (val) return "Да";
         return "Нет";
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для отображения даты в конфигурируемом формате данных используйте 
`StringFormat='{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'`